# CSS3 animation not working with gradient background in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

I've **already checked existing posts** on this topic, but those solutions didn't work.

I have a simple `CSS3` background animation. Works fine ion `Chrome` & `IE`, but does not work in Firefox. I'm currently using `Firefox developer edition v46.0a2 (2016-02-28)`. Here is the style.

```
@-webkit-keyframes danger {
    0%   {background-color: orange;}
    50%  {background-color: red;}
    100% {background-color: orange;}
}
@keyframes danger {
    0%  {background: radial-gradient(circle, #ff1a1a, #ff5050, #ff5500);}
    50%  {background: radial-gradient(circle, #b30000, #ff0000, #ff471a);}
    100%  {background: radial-gradient(circle, #ff1a1a, #ff5050, #ff5500);}
}
.blink {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff1a1a; /*rgba(256, 0, 0, 1.0); /*#de6363;*/
    -webkit-animation: danger 0.3s infinite;
    animation: danger 0.3s infinite;
}
```

Please check this **[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pswz0g3c/)**.

Comment: add `-moz-animation: danger 0.3s infinite;`

Comment: @Chris Have tried that already, didn't work!

Comment: If you change the `radial-gradient(...);`s inside of the `@keyframes` rule to static colors (`orange` or `red`) then the animation will run, making it seem like the issue is with the `radial-gradients`

Comment: Okay, seems the problem is with your radial gradient not working in keyframe in firefox. Googling suggests that this is a known issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that firefox is not supporting radial-gradients with that particolar use; if you try the following code

```
@keyframes danger {
  0%   {background-color: orange;}
  50%  {background-color: red;}
  100% {background-color: orange;}
}
```

The animation works in FF. Also the following definitions of radial-gradient works:

```
background: radial-gradient(#7B7878 1%, #BBBBBB 30%, #CCCCCC 40%, #FFF 70%);
background: radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636);
```

Comment: Looks like this works, I'll check properly when I get some time. Thanks!